# Why CDI unsatisfied dependency when using annotation parameter?

Tags: java, annotations, glassfish, cdi

I've defined a qualifier to specify what bean subclass I want injected.  When the qualifier has no parameters specified at the injection point, everything works as expected.  When I specify an attribute and value at the injection point, I get a CDI unsatisfied dependency error. I'm deploying on Glassfish 4.0.  Also, using no-interface view on the injected beans, but I didn't think that mattered in this situation.

The purpose of the qualifier is to get a Postgres-specific subclass (a variety of different db's are being used, to compare any behavioral differences).  The parameter is to specify the Postgres schema (which defaults to "public").

The qualifier is defined like this in `Postgres.java`:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface Postgres
{
  String schema() default "public";
}
```

The injected subclass looks like this in `DBCmdPostgres.java`:

```
@Stateless
@Postgres
public class DBCmdPostgres
    extends DBCmd
{
...
  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct()
  {
    Class cl = getClass();
    Postgres postgresAnnotation = (Postgres)cl.getAnnotation(Postgres.class);
    if (postgresAnnotation != null) {
      System.out.println(">> @Postgres(schema = " + postgresAnnotation.schema() +")");
    }
  }
...
}
```

The base class looks like this in `DBCmd.java` :

```
@Stateless
@Default
abstract public class DBCmd
{
...
}
```

And the injection point is this in a JSF session-scoped backing bean `indexBacker.java`:

```
  @Inject @Postgres(schema = "foo") private DBCmd postgresCmds;
```

If I leave out the `(schema = "foo")` at the injection point, things work as I'd expect, and the PostConstruct method displays the proper default of "public".  If I add the `(schema = "foo")` part, I get the following error on deployment to Glassfish:

```
[2013-09-18T08:36:24.209-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1379511384209] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [DBCmd] with qualifiers [@Postgres] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Postgres private jsfBackers.IndexBacker.postgresCmds]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [DBCmd] with qualifiers [@Postgres] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Postgres private jsfBackers.IndexBacker.postgresCmds]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
...
```

The beans are currently `@Stateless`, but will become `@Stateful` (to store/use the value of the `schema` parameter, as well as some other stuff) if we can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter should be marked as `@Nonbinding` in order to properly resolve like this.

To read the value:

where ip is your `InjectionPoint` object, `annotationClass` is the class you want to read (T is the type of it)

```
final Set<Annotation> annotations = ip.getQualifiers();
        for (final Annotation a : annotations) {
            try {
                if (a.annotationType().isAssignableFrom(annotationClass)) {
                    t = (T) a;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            }
        }`
```

Comment: Adding @Nonbinding solves the problem. Thanks. If I may ask the followup:  Is there a way to find the value of the "schema" attribute from within the postConstruct() method of the DBCmdPostgres class that's getting an instance injected?   All the examples I've found have been based on using reflection on the class that declares the annotated field -- but I need to do this from within the class instance being injected into the annotated field, not its "parent".   I think if walking the stack is necessary to do this, I'd rather find another solution.

Comment: Updated my answer with the defacto way of doing that.

Comment: Perfect.  The key piece I was missing was adding `@Inject InjectionPoint ip` into the injected class.  Obviously, I still have much to learn. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  In fact, that's actually what I ended up doing.